# barplot with N distinct colors shade in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have a bar chart of N bars I built with python matplotlib.pyplot.bar and I would like to give each bar a different color following a shaded off:

for example if N = 4, I would like: yellow, orange, light red, dark red. I would like to stay in the yellow-red tonalities.

But I want the shade to take N as a parameter.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the color maps to accomplish what you want. There are a lot of color maps available, pick your favourite or make your own.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# number of bars
N = 20

# plot a random bar graph
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bars = ax.bar(np.arange(N), np.random.random(N))

# change the colors according to the color map 'jet'
for i, b in enumerate(bars):
    b.set_color(plt.cm.jet(1. * i / (N - 1)))
```

This creates:

[image]

So, there are two points:

- when the bar graph is drawn, `bar` returns a collection of bars
- the color of each bar is changed by giving the desired color map an argument between 0..1 (here leftmost is 0 and rightmost 1, but you may pick only a small part of the color map if you want)

Defining your own color maps is easy, as well. Or if you only want to have a linear transition between two colors, you may skip using the color map altogether and make your own calculations. `set_color` expects to receive a color name or a 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) element iterable.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer !